# How to migrate string field to enum?

Tags: spring, jpa

I have two versions of a product entity that I have migrate data from one to the other. The "unit" attribute is the problem. The original keeps kilogram unit as "kg" and after migration it should be persisted as "kilogram".

The new product entity has:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Unit unit;
```

I wrote a converter:

```
    @Converter(autoApply = true)
    public class UnitConverter implements AttributeConverter<Unit, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Unit attribute) {

        switch (attribute) {

        case KG:
            return "kg";
        case LT:
            return "lt";
        case MT:
            return "mt";
        case PCS:
            return "pcs";

        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public Unit convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {

        switch (dbData) {

        case "kg":
            return Unit.KG;
        case "lt":
            return Unit.LT;
        case "mt":
            return Unit.MT;
        case "pcs":
            return Unit.PCS;

        }

        return null;

    }

}
```

And tried

```
public Unit unit;
```

But I get

> Invalid value for getInt() - 'kg'

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:801) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:782) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:769) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at erp.migration.MigrationApplication.main(MigrationApplication.java:21) [bin/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at erp.migration.CommandRunner.migrateMaterials(CommandRunner.java:110) ~[bin/:na]
    at erp.migration.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:99) ~[bin/:na]
    at erp.migration.CommandRunner$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d69da090.invoke(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at erp.migration.CommandRunner$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8bb3a8a3.run(<generated>) ~[bin/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2620) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:327) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:280) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'kg'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2517) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2583) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType$OrdinalEnumValueMapper.getValue(EnumType.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2727) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1729) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1544) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Did you specify the @Column on your Unit Attribute ?

Comment: If you need unit attribute must be a column in your database, you need add @Column and @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) annnotations.

Comment: Annotation '@Column' shouldn't be necessary as I can get the unit values from the db fine. '@Enumerated' makes the field ignore the converter.